# This hit starts a new session, most likely because the client ID changed. where is the mistake?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

i have site1 and site2...

in the site1:

```js
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-хххх"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-ххх', {
            'linker': {
                'domains': ['site1', 'site2']
            }
        });
    </script>
```

in the site2:

```js
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-хххх"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-ххх', {
            'linker': {
                'domains': ['site1', 'site2']
            }
        });
    </script>
```

site1: source domain 
site2: destination domain

I have two sessions displayed
displays: This hit starts a new session, most likely because the client ID changed. This is caused by an improper tracking code implementation.
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add site2 to "Referral Exclusion List" in Google Analytics account for these sites.

*Property Settings --> Tracking Info --> Referral Exclusion List*